# Run a solution from Visual Studio console without opening the IDE

Tags: visual-studio-2010, command-line, msbuild, console, devenv

I am using [Visual Studio 2010](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2010) SP1.

What I first tried was this:

1. Open the Visual Studio console tool from start menu
2. Navigate to project folder (which already contains an executable)
3. Run: `msbuild myproject.sln or msbuild myproject.sln /p:Configuration=Release`
4. This builds successfully, but I can't find an executable to run

1. The second thing I tried was steps 1 and 2 from above
2. Running: `devenv myproject.sln /Build and devenv myproject.sln /Run`
3. This somewhat works but it seems to open the IDE to run the build
4. The whole point was to avoid using the ide at all.

Now, how do I build and run a solution without opening the IDE?

**--------------------------FIXED------------------------------**

The problem was that I was looking in the wrong place for the executable (noob mistake). I ended up using this batch file:

```
msbuild myproj.sln /p:configuration=Release
cd (("Path to executable" usually in the Debug/Release Folder))
myExecutableName
cd (("Path to original folder"))
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

- Navigate to your solution folder
- Run: msbuild myproject.sln /p:Configuration=Release (or Debug)
- cd myproject  (within your solution folder - it's a sub-folder)
- cd bin
- cd Release (or Debug)
- Run: myproject.exe

You can replace the three separate `cd` commands with a single one:

```
cd myproject\bin\Release
```

Or simply run your executable from the solution folder:

```
myproject\bin\Release\myproject.exe
```

Comment: I ended up making a batch file which builds, navigates, runs and navigates back.

Comment: Yep, that would be much easier. I figured you'd work that part out. :-)