# Access Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt from regular Command Prompt

Tags: windows, visual-studio, command-prompt

[This related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15754302/run-a-solution-from-visual-studio-console-without-opening-the-ide) shows how to build and run a Visual Studio solution from Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt. My question is, is it possible to build and run a Visual Studio solution directly from the regular Windows Command Prompt (cmd.exe)?

Comment: Can you define "run a visual studio solution"? Do you mean Build a visual studio solution? Open it in Visual Studio? or simply run the outcomes of a previous build?

Comment: @jessehouwing, I want to build and run the solution without opening the VS IDE, but from the regular command prompt only. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I found the answer.

1. Access VS Developer Command Prompt from regular command prompt.

> ```
> C:\Users\Hwathanie>cmd.exe /k ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio 12.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" x86
> ```

2. Build the solution.

> ```
> C:\Users\Hwathanie>msbuild "C:\Users\Hwathanie\Documents\Visual
> Studio 2013\Projects\MyProject\MyProject.sln" /p:Configuration=Debug
> ```

3. Run the exe file created.

> ```
> C:\Users\Hwathanie>"C:\Users\Hwathanie\Documents\Visual Studio 2
> 013\Projects\MyProject\bin\Debug\MyProject.exe"
> ```